# How should I go about scanning a file to an array or arraylist so that the file can be manipulated or read back to the user?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, arraylist

I'm new here so I'm sorry if I'm breaking some kind of rule.

Anyway, I'm currently taking a Java class and we were assigned this project. The point of the project is to use inheritance to write this program. I am meant to make a "phone directory" of sorts where the user can scan in the file using a scanner and use methods to carry out certain tasks.
My professor lists these as requirements for my program...the program needs to:

- Display the entire directory
- Using a Binary search Java method written by you, you may use the one you wrote in class, to 
  display the contents of a particular entry
- Delete an existing entry
- Insert an entry to the directory, maintaining the sorted order
- Save the entire directory to a file

I thought using an arraylist would be the most efficient way to do this.

Here is the code I am using to scan the text file in:

```
private Scanner fileIn;
private ArrayList<String> directory = new ArrayList<String>();

public void scanFile() {
    try {
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("directory.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Please make sure the directory file is actually there.");
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine. I forgot to mention this, but we are allowed to have any format we deem neccesary in our directory tester file - this is the format I follow in my tester file:

```
cat,alex,200 meowtown lane,trumbull,ct,06117,3005729384/
```

I plan to use the / at the end as some sort of delimiter to tell Java "hey this is one complete object!"

This is where things get a bit tricky for me. To do everything I need to do for this program, I need to scan it all into the directory arraylist I made. I cannot find an efficient way to do this.

I want to be able to scan each object in (by line) meaning every person will have their own line. Within each line I need to be able to pick pieces of data out of the line. For example, I want to manipulate the zip code in a line so I should be able to pick it out somehow.

I thought about making a second scanner to do this, but I honestly don't know how I would do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Start by storing each record on an individual line.  This will allow you to use `fileIn.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the `split` method on a `,`.

Assuming you are putting one line per entry, you don't need to worry about the `/`, as that would give you the separation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine()`

For exemple:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = inFile.nextLine();
    list.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Why "ArrayList<String> list".  Wouldn't "List<String> list" be better?

Answer (score 0):

First, create an `Class` which represents the basic concept of an entry, for example...

```
public class DirectoryEntry {
    // Add fields and methods as required
    // Provide a simple constructor that will allow you to supply
    // the basic values for the available fields...
}
```

Next, place each entry within your `directory.txt` file on it's own line, this will allow you to simply use `Scanner#hasNextLine` and `Scanner#nextLine` to read the file.

Read the file, parsing each line so that you can split it into it's individual field elements, create a new instance `DirectoryEntry` and add it to some kind of `java.util.List`, for example

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestFileScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileIn = null;
        List<DirectoryEntry> enrties = new ArrayList<>(25);
        try {
            fileIn = new Scanner(new File("directory.txt"));
            while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = fileIn.nextLine();
                // Parse the individual line elements...
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(...);
                enrties.add(de);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```